# C++ Stop while loop at the end of the line (enter Key)

Tags: c++, while-loop, printing, text-processing

**Task:**
Create program to read given text file and print into another text file all lines containing given substring. Reading from files should be carried out line per line.

**My code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream file; // required for input file further processing
    ofstream outputFile; 
    string word1, word2, t, q, inputFileName;

    string keyWord = "morning";
    string enterKey = "\n";
  
    inputFileName = "inputFile.txt";
    file.open(inputFileName.c_str());  // opening the EXISTING INPUT file

    outputFile.open("outputFile.txt"); // CREATION of OUTPUT file

    // extracting words from the INPUT file
    while (file >> word1){
        if(word1 == keyWord) {
            while(file >> word2 && word2 != enterKey){
                // printing the extracted words to the OUTPUT file
                outputFile << word2 << " ";
            }
        }
        
    }

    outputFile.close();
  
    return 0;
}
```

**1st problem:**
outputFile contains the whole text, in other words while loop is not stopping at the place whre enter is pressed.

**2nd problem:**
Processing of string is not starting from the beginning of the text.

Comment: Try `std::getline` the `>>` operator discards all whitespace including newlines

Comment: Quick suggestion - If you are using UNIX like systems (eg Linux, MacOS), you can use the command 'cat inputFile.txt | grep morning > outputFile.txt' to get the desired results.

Comment: Alan Birtles, Abdus Khazi, thank you for the suggestions, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are reading word by word. A stream uses "\n" as a token seperater. Hence it is ignored during word reading. Use getline standard function to get a line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string inputFileName = "inputFile.txt";
    string outputFileName = "outputFile.txt";

    fstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputFile; 

    inputfile.open(inputFileName.c_str());
    outputFile.open(outputFileName.c_str());

    string keyWord = "morning";
    string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        // Processing from the beginning of each line.
        if(line.find(keyWord) != string::npos)
            outputFile << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

Got the idea from the answer in [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c/7868998#7868998)